# How to log the MQ delivery time in Apache camel for Dynamic delivery (toD)?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to get time taken for a message just to be delivered to the IBM MQ queues in Apache Camel. Below is the route configuration,

```
from("direct:deliver-route-2").process("mySampleProcessor").split().method("messageSplitterBean", "splitMessage").shareUnitOfWork().stopOnException().toD("mqDeliverJms:${headers.Deliver}?preserveMessageQos=true");
```

I have a splitter in place to split the list of messages and dynamically deliver (toD) it using the messages header "Deliver".

I used the MessageHistory suggestion given in one of the questions, but then I don't  see the elapsed time for the (toD) delivery of the messages to IBM MQ.

```
String MessageHist = org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper.dumpMessageHistoryStacktrace(exchange,
                new DefaultExchangeFormatter(), false);
```

Here is the message history,

[image]

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: The Camel version is 2.18.4

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'EventNotifier' to capture the `ExchangeSent` events where you have the time, eg there is little example in the Camel docs at: http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

Comment: Thanks Claus, I am able to get the MQ delivery times by applying the endpoint type filter on the 'Event Notifier'.
`if (sentEvent.getEndpoint() instanceof JmsQueueEndpoint)`